# Factorize the $4 \times 4$ determinant by a $2 \times 2$ determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Factorize
> \begin{vmatrix}
> a & -b & -a & b\\
> b & a & -b & -a\\
> c & -d & 2c & -2d\\
> d & c & 2d & 2c
> \end{vmatrix} by $$\begin{vmatrix}
> A & -A\\
> B & 2B
> \end{vmatrix} =3^n |A||B|,$$ where *A* and *B* are *n* power matrices.

Here is my thinking:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & -b & -a & b \\
b & a & -b & -a \\
c & -d & 2c & -2d \\
d & c & 2d & 2c
\end{vmatrix} \xrightarrow[C_4 +C_2]{C_3 +C_1} \begin{vmatrix}
a & -b & 0 & 0 \\
b & a & 0 & 0 \\
c & -d & 3c & -3d \\
d & c & 3d & 3c
\end{vmatrix} \xrightarrow[R_1 \leftrightarrow R_2 ,\; R_2 \leftrightarrow R_3]{C_3 \leftrightarrow C_2} -\begin{vmatrix}
b & 0 & a & 0 \\
c & 3c & -d & -3d \\
a & 0 & -b & 0 \\
d & 3d & c & 3c
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$\begin{vmatrix}
A & -A \\
B & 2B
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
A & 0 \\
B & 3B
\end{vmatrix} = 3^n |A||B|$$

$$-\begin{vmatrix}
b & 0 & a & 0 \\
c & 3c & -d & -3d \\
a & 0 & -b & 0 \\
d & 3d & c & 3c
\end{vmatrix} = -\left(\begin{vmatrix}
b & 0 \\
c & 3c
\end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}
a & 0 \\
-d & -3d
\end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}
a & 0 \\
d & 3d
\end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix}
-b & 0 \\
c & 3c
\end{vmatrix}\right)$$

$$= -( 3bc\times (-3ab) \times 3ab\times (-3bc)) = -81a^2 b^2 c^2 d^2$$

The result I got seems to be weird. It can never turn to expression of first degree.

Please let me know where is wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the given matrix we can see $A=\left(\begin{matrix}
a & -b\\ b & a \end{matrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{matrix}
c & -d\\ d & c\end{matrix}\right).$

Comment: @user376343 YES. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what "$n-$ power matrices" means.

If $A,B$   are square matrices of the same size, we have

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & -A\\
B & 2B
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
I & 0\\
\frac{-1}{2}I & I
\end{pmatrix}  =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{3}{2}A & -A\\
0 & 2B
\end{pmatrix}  
$$
which is block triangular, while the determinant is $\frac{3}{2} \det A \; \; 2 \det B = 3 \det A \det B $

Comment: I'm sorry the description confused you. "A and B are a square matrix of order n" may be appropriate.